# Как таблицу сузить Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Я через бутстрап создал таблицу но она на всю страницу, как можно ее так сжать чтобы она была не на всю страницу по длине.
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Вот мой код

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>All Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <h3>List of all Students</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>
                     <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить студента</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Советую поиграться и посмотреть разные свойства на сайте htmlbooks.ru Вы видимо не понимаете и не смотрите точные изменения в коде, как и вчера с кнопками. И скорее всего, просто берете и вставляете код из ответов. Прежде чем работать с bootstrap, поиграетесь с обычным CSS

Comment: Поставь в стилях  width: auto  <table class="table" style="width: auto;">